# Is it bad practice to mutate your HttpClient objects?

Tags: design, c#, dependency-injection, http, .net-core

Im in the process of creating a base class for typed `HttpClient` services (yes, I'm utilizing `IHttpClientFactory`). I wrote the process in such a way that for each CRUD method invoked from the service, the first thing said service does is check for and assign an access token to attach to the `HttpClient` header. Example:

```
public abstract class BaseNetworkService : IBaseNetworkService {
   protected HttpClient _httpClient { get; }

   public BaseNetworkService(HttpClient client, ...) {
      _httpClient = client;
   }
   
   public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string extendedUrl, ICacheContext cacheContext = null) {
      ... check Redis Cache, return result if there ...
      
      Http client = GetcurrentAccessToken(_httpClient);
      var response = await client.GetAsync(extendedUrl);
      ...
   }
}
```

I'll admit upfront that I am not entirely sure why I have always made my `HttpClients` **readonly** and upon Googling for answers, it's probably because every document and guide on `HttpClient` with dependency injection makes the client readonly. I didn't find any material explaining the reason for that.

With that in mind, should your `HttpClient`remain readonly? Should any customization, such as attaching an access token, be done in the classes constructor?

Comment: The `readonly` keyword does not prevent you from mutating the client. It prevents you from replacing the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword does not prevent mutability of an object. It only makes sure that you do not replace it by doing `myReadonlyObject = new Object()`.

As for why your `HttpClient` is `readonly` - because there is no need to ever replace it with a new `HttpClient`. In fact, in case of `HttpClient`, you should be aiming to reuse it, instead of creating a new client for each web request. That is how `HttpClient` [was designed to be used](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).

The reason for that is, that even after your request went through, you got the response and the connection was closed, the underlying socket still stays open and listens for any packets that might have been delayed in the network traffic. This is obviously not a huge deal if the application only makes a couple of requests and is done. However it might become a bigger issue when we make tens of thousands requests in relatively short amount of time and use a new instance of `HttpClient` for each request, since the amount of sockets that can be open at once is limited by the OS.

Comment: ` Http client = GetcurrentAccessToken(_httpClient);` So this would leave an underlying socket open?

Comment: @8protons Yes, for a while. In Windows it's around 4 minutes. So ideally you would not create new HttpClients, and instead reuse one instance of it throughout the whole application run time to avoid having too many open sockets.

Comment: Just to add to this, HttpClient is an awful footgun as this excellent blog post from 2016 shows ( https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/ ). Ive personally seen this happen in production, and it is awful to troubleshoot. Always reuse one instance of it if you use it. Or use some of the other http client libraries on .net that doesnt have this awful design built in.

Comment: @Aleksander Are you sure? Because the initial http client is managed watched by IHttpClientFactory. When I created a new instance and closed the original, the clone seemed to close as well.

Comment: @8protons How and where are you creating a new instance?

Comment: @Aleksander I was doing something like `HttpClient newClient = IHeader.AttachHeaders(_httpClient);` The _httpClient was injected into the constructor of the file where this code lives, and that was setup in the Startup.cs with AddHttpClient(), utilizing `IHttpClientFactory`.

Comment: @8protons Attach header attached the header to the passed _httpClient and returns it back?

Comment: @Aleksander Yes, exactly.

Comment: @8protons Then you are clearly not creating a new instance but instead you are modifying the existing _httpClient. After that line of code executes, your newClient is not actually a new client, but the same client you passed to AttachHeaders(), just altered.